# Two pointers pointing to a same memory and realloc failing

Tags: pointers, realloc

```
void container_row_change(struct brick_win_size *win, int character)
{
    row_container *container = &(win->container[win->current_row]);
    /*int offset = win->current_column;
    char *data = win->container[win->current_row]. data;
    if(offset < 0 || offset >= win->col)
        offset = container->size;

    data = realloc(data, win->container[win->current_row].size + 2 );
    memmove(&data[offset + 1], &data[offset], (win->container[win->current_row].size  - offset + 1));
    data[offset] = character;
    win->current_column++;
    container->size ++;
   */

   int offset = win->current_column;
   if(offset < 0 || offset >= win->col)
        offset = container->size;
   win->container[win->current_row].data = realloc(win->container[win->current_row]. data,      win->container[win->current_row]. size + 2);
   memmove(&(win->container[win->current_row].data[offset + 1]), &(win->container[win->current_row].data[offset]), win->container[win->current_row].size - offset + 1);
   win->container[win->current_row].data[offset] =character;
   win->current_column++;
   win->container[win->current_row].size ++;

}
```

Can anybody tell why the commented line fails and not the other one although both are same? 
I am wondering is there any errors in the way I assign pointers and reallocate it

Comment: Which particular line are you talking about?

Comment: The whole commented section... more specifically.............                                             data = realloc(data, win->container[win->current_row].size + 2 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commented out code, you realloc the local pointer `data` and never update the `.data` pointer field in the data structure, so it continues to point at the old (now freed) memory, leading to corruption when you try to use it.

Add the line `win->container[win->current_row].data = data;` to the commented out code and it will actually be equivalent to the later code.

Note that in either case, if realloc fails, you'll crash -- you should be checking for failure and doing something appropriate (probably printing an error message and trying to exit gracefully).

Comment: Ya, Thanks for the answer Chris. Found out myself after two hours after posting this question lol, I indeed ended up in having a headache anyways. For those error check ill for sure add those in my project mate.